# Dynamics 365 OData getting 1:N linked entities

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I have entities of type `account` which when I look at it in Dyn365 it has a section containing a list view of related entities. How do i get these related entities from the OData API?

I can query `api/data/v9.1/account` but the related entities do not appear anywhere in the resulting json.

If I do the same for the related entities the account do not appear anywhere. How do I get the link between these two types of entities? using the OData API.

I've tried things like `/accounts?$expand=contact($select=foo)` but it just says contact property do not exist on the account entity, which is correct. But contact is not a property its an entity type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to use the following url to get the names of all relationships.

```
https://<company>.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/RelationshipDefinitions?$select=SchemaName
```

Result is an array of the following rows for each relationship.

```
{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.OneToManyRelationshipMetadata","SchemaName":"aaa_bbb","MetadataId":"<guid>"},
```

Then use those names, specifically the `SchemaName` property in the `$expand` query parameter.

```
https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts?
$select=<whatever>&
$expand=aaa_bbb($select=<properties from linked entity>)
```

To figure out what relationship actually do what you need, you need to read in more then just the SchemaName if you can't guess what is what, or look it up in Dynamics through the GUI if you know how and have access. I don't.

The `RelationshipDefinition` contains other properties like `ReferencedEntity` `ReferencingEntity` that can be used to determine if you got the right relationship.

Comment: ok, so you are looking for Metadata API to pull the name dynamically. good to know

Comment: @ArunVinoth not dynamicly, but i don't know how to look up the relationship names for the different entities inside Dynamics, and im not sure i have access. So i've just hardcoded the relationship names in the code to navigate the entity graph.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, this is what you are looking for. The relationship for 1:N between account and contact is `contact_customer_accounts`

All accounts with its related contacts:

```
https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts?$select=name&$expand=contact_customer_accounts($select=fullname)
```

Particular account with related contacts:

```
https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts(73C84814-729B-EA11-A811-000D3A370DB6)?$select=name&$expand=contact_customer_accounts($select=fullname)
```

Comment: what is the logic behind this? what if i have two entites `Aaa` and `Bbb` is the link entity between them then named `aaa_bbb`?

Comment: @CodeMonkey that’s purely depends on how you create relationships and what name you are giving. This account/contact entities has some complex relationships. You can browse using metadata browser in XRMToolbox